# I'm trying to set alert for when the indicator turns lime or maroon

Tags: pine-script

```
src=close
len = input(18)
OB=76.4, OS=23.6
smooth = input(true, title="Smooth")

lowerBand = 5
PI= 3.14159265358979
ssFilter( price, lowerBand ) =>
   angle = sqrt(2)*PI/lowerBand
   a1= exp(-angle)
   b1 = 2*al*cos(angle)
   C2 = b1
   c3 = -a1*a1
   c1 = 1 - c2-c3
   filt = c1*(price + nz(price[1]))/2 + c2*nz(filt[1]) + c3*nz(filt[2])

sentiment(len) =>
   lowest = lowest(src, len)
   highest = highest(src,len)
   diffBull = (src-lowest)*100/lowest
   diffBear = (highest-src)*100/highest
   bbs = diffBull*100/(diffBear + diffBull)
   bbSentiment = smooth?ssFilter(bbs, lowerBand): bbs

bbSentiment = sentiment(len)

// Output
plot(bbSentiment, color=change(bbSentiment)>=0?lime: maroon, linewidth=1)
```

I'm trying to set alert for when the indicator turns lime or maroon

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as text

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alertcondition()` to trigger alerts.

Ideally, you only want to have an alert when the color changes. That means, when the previous color is not the same as the current one. To check that, you can use the [history reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) `[]`.

Change the last part of your script to this:

```
bbSentiment = sentiment(len)
bb_lime = change(bbSentiment)>=0
bb_maroon = not bb_lime

alertcondition(bb_lime and not bb_lime[1], "Lime", "Color changing to lime")
alertcondition(bb_maroon and not bb_maroon[1], "Maroon", "Color changing to maroon")

// Output
plot(bbSentiment, color=bb_lime ? lime : maroon, linewidth=1)
```